# What are OpenGL secondary colors useful for?

Tags: opengl

`glSecondaryColor` allows to specify a 2nd color. What is this second color useful for?

I have checked the [kronos reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glSecondaryColor.xml) and it does not help much:

> The secondary color is interpolated and applied to each fragment
>   during rasterization when GL_COLOR_SUM is enabled.  When lighting is
>   enabled, and GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR is specified, the value of the
>   secondary color is assigned the value computed from the specular term
>   of the lighting computation. Both the primary and secondary current
>   colors are applied to each fragment, regardless of the state of
>   GL_COLOR_SUM, under such conditions.  When GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR
>   is specified, the value returned from querying the current secondary
>   color is undefined.

This secondary color thing could even look like leftovers from older GL versions... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the fixed-function lighting model, the primary color and/or texture color is applied to the diffuse lighting *and* the specular lighting. Therefore, it was impossible to have a shiny black surface, since the black primary color/texture color would be multiplied into the specular lighting, making it effectively zero.

Providing a secondary color and enabling `GL_SEPARATE_SPECULAR_COLOR` would mean that the specular lighting value would be multiplied into the secondary color instead of the primary color. So you could have a black primary/texture color, with a secondary color of 1.0. That would allow you to have a bright shiny highlight even in dark areas of the surface.

Of course, this is all fixed-function trash that was discarded in GL 3.1. With shaders, you can have whatever lighting model you can code.